# Insert bulk data in postreSQL / TimescaleDB and manage errors

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a script that select rows from InfluxDB, and bulk insert it into TimescaleDB.

I am inserting data each 2000 rows, to make it faster.

Thing is when I get one error, all 2000 rows is ignored. Is it possible to insert the 1999 rows, and ignore the failing one ?

Comment: It depends on how you are doing the bulk inserts, and what kind of errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Since PostgreSQL implements ACID transactions, the entire transaction is rollbacked on an error. The minimal granularity for transaction is one statement, e.g., `INSERT INTO` statement with batch of values, and this is default. So if failure happens, it is not possible to ignore it and commit the rest.

I assume you use [`INSERT INTO` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html). It provides `ON CONFLICT` clause, which can be used in the case if the observed error is due to conflict.

Another work around is to move into a temporal table and then insert into hypertable after cleaning.

BTW, have you looked to [Outflux tool from Timescale](https://github.com/timescale/outflux) if it can help?